# Primitive makefile failure for compiling

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to learn makefile, but I fail badly.
One example (which is very primitive) but I should understand it to go ahead is this one

```
f90_simple: f1.o  
    gfortran f1.o
     mv a.out f90_simple  
f90_simple.o:   f1.f90
    gfortran -c f1.f90
```

it does not work, and I get this error
I get this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `f1.o', needed by `f90_simple'.  Stop.
```

could you please advise me?

thanks

Comment: edit your Q to include the output of `uname -srv ; make -v` . Do you have tab chars for the indented sections (old `makes` require that). I would also add a black line between sections. Also if MS-Windows was involved in the creating or moving of that file, use `cat -ver makefile` and if you see `^M$` at the end of each line, use `dos2unix makefile` to cleanit up for the linux environment. Good luck.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Please show the command you typed and the errors you receive.

Comment: @MadScientist I get this error make: *** No rule to make target `f1.o', needed by `f90_simple'.  Stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule says that before `f90_simple` can be built, the target `f1.o` must be built.

But there's no rule in your makefile that tells make how to build the target `f1.o`, and make can't find any built-in rule that can build it (based on the source files make has available), so it prints that error.

You do have a rule that tells make how to build a target `f90_simple.o`... but that's not the target make is looking for.  Most likely you want your makefile to either be:

```
f90_simple: f1.o  
        gfortran $^
        mv a.out $@

f1.o: f1.f90
        gfortran -o $@ -c $<
```

or else:

```
f90_simple: f90_simple.o  
        gfortran $^
        mv a.out $@

f90_simple.o: f1.f90
        gfortran -o $@ -c $<
```

but you can't mix and match them, or make doesn't know what to do.

I think you would really benefit from reading at least the introductory chapters in [The GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-An-Introduction-to-Makefiles).